# Отображение степени в EditText

Tags: java, android, math

Возможно ли в Java, как в Word, записать число в степени в переменную типа `String`.
При этом считать его? Знаю что возможно записать степень числа как:

> 1.0E20

Если нету стандартных возможностей, возможно ли написать свой парсер?

**UPDATE**

Есть некоторые длинные числа, которые я хочу записывать в формате 1.11 * 10^**12**. есть ли возможность записывать степень как в ворде в вверху. 
  Отобразить в `EditText`.

Comment: Можно конкретнее, что вы хотите сдлеать? Что должно быть на входе, и что на выходе (с примерами)?

Comment: @Nofate так понятнее?

Comment: Записывать где? При выводе на консоль? В swing- приложении?

Comment: @Nofate в EditText андроида

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант – можно воспользоваться классом `Html` для форматирования текста:

```
private static CharSequence formatPower(String source) {
    int powerPosition = source.indexOf("E");
    if (powerPosition == -1) {
        return source;
    }
    String numberValue = source.substring(0, powerPosition);
    String powerValue = source.substring(powerPosition + 1);
    return fromHtml(numberValue + "<sup>" + powerValue + "</sup>");
}

private static Spanned fromHtml(String html) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
    } else {
        return Html.fromHtml(html);
    }
}
```

И далее:

```
mEditText.setText(formatPower("1.0E20"));
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Всё работает.